# Looping through multilayer json Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, freebase

Hi i'm quite new to jquery and json so please bear with me. I have searched the forums and tried a lot of different things to solve my problem.

I'm trying to loop through a multilayer JSON file form Freebase.

```
$.getJSON(service_url + topic_id + '?callback=?', params, function(topic) {
$("#free").append('<h3>Description</h3><p>'+topic.property['/common/topic/description'].values[0].value+'</p>');
        $("#title").prepend('<h2>'+topic.property['/type/object/name'].values[0].value+'<span><a class="socila-link" style="color:#3b5998;" href="'+topic.property['/common/topic/social_media_presence'].values[0].value+'"> <i class="icon-facebook-sign"></i></a><a class="socila-link" style="color:#0084B4" href="'+topic.property['/common/topic/social_media_presence'].values[2].value+'"> <i class="icon-twitter-sign"></i></a></span></h2>')
        $("#fb-span1").append('<p><strong>Official Website: </strong><a href="'+topic.property['/common/topic/official_website'].values[0].value+'">'+topic.property['/common/topic/official_website'].values[0].value+'</a></p>');
        $("#fb-span1").append('<p><strong>Genre: </strong>'+topic.property['/music/artist/genre'].values[0].text+'</p>');
        $("#fb-span1").append('<p><strong>Founded: </strong>'+topic.property['/music/artist/active_start'].values[0].text+'</p>');
        $("#fb-span1").append('<p><strong>Hometown: </strong>'+topic.property['/music/artist/origin'].values[0].text+'</p>');

        $.each(topic.property, function(i, val)  {

 $("#fb-span1").append('<p><strong>Genre: </strong>'+val['/music/artist/genre'].values['text']+'</p>');
});
```

I have no problems getting the result if i enter the value like [0], but i cant seem to loop through it.Nothing gets returnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the getJSON call you don't need any jQuery to do this. You can just access the JSON data as regular Javascript arrays and dictionaries. So to output multiple values from the array of "Genre" property values you can just use a for loop like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<topic.property['/music/artist/genre'].values.length; i++) {
  var val = topic.property['/music/artist/genre'].values[i];
  $("#fb-span1").append('<p><strong>Genre: </strong>'+val['text']+'</p>');
}
```

Comment: Thx Shawn, that solved it for me. I love the potential of freebase for building exciting dynamic websites! Good job from you guys :)